# Password Reset Email

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Within a Symfony2 application I'm building I've managed to get user account creation, login, updating profile working using bootstrap for the frontend and 'out of the box' Symfony2 for the rest. I need to add the ability for users to reset their passwords and/or have email sent with a generated password. I'll preface these questions with the fact I am new to developing in Symfony2. My questions are 1) Do I try and use FOSUserBundle in parallel with code I have already written or 2) Are there ways to implement this without FOSUserBundle. These are questions are really coming from a place of not knowing any better.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a symfony guy but I only know that Symfony embraces the "don't reinvent the wheel" philosophy. Symfony itself is a collection of bundles. If this is your first time with a web framework I can tell that you've passed a lot of time and effort implementing something that other developers offered to you. Believe me if you want to build something powerful and standardized  FOSuserbundle will undoubtedly satisfy your need.

Answer (score 1):

Always sad to see a genuinely asked question downvoted.

@Brent was a Symfony novice myself and in many ways probably still am. I wouldn't say Symfony embraces "don't reinvent the wheel" but rather "speed up app development". I am sure you can take days searching Stackoverflow and find possible (probably a little bit outdated) solutions to your problem or do as @AzizFCB suggested and use a ready Symfony bundle, in fact, the most widely used and adopted Symfony bundle. Unless your app's core activity is solving people's login and forgot password problems. I would strongly advise to use FOSUserBundle, solve that problem in a few hours importantly including updates (especially security) that you don't need to manage (but if you can please contribute to) and focus your efforts on coding your apps core activity(s).